# How can I check if .dll are part of the .net 2.0 Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, frameworks

I use "user32.dll" and "kernel32" for centering a MessageBox in the center of the form. My concern is that I will have to run this app on the .net 2.0 framework and I do not know if this will be an issue. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*user32* and *kernel32* are part of Windows, not of Microsoft .NET, so if you use your app on Windows the only problem could be that the specific API you are using have been introduced in newer versions of Windows. Go to MSDN and check them.

Comment: That means it should work on windows server too then. Thanks a lot!